# How to implement a Drag and Drop ImageView in Cocoa-Touch?

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, uiimageview

How can I drag images in my app (more than two ) because it's working with two images but want  to drag about 20 images at the same view

Comment: how should you drag 20 images at once? you should explain a little bit more.

Comment: I want to put 20 images in the view and the user could move any image drag and drop it

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is, to add an `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to each view, that should be draggable.

Or you could write a `UIView`-subclass and overwrite `TouchesBegan, TouchesMoved and TouchesEnded`. So every view handles its own touches for dragging.

If you want to see an example, perhaps my `JDDroppableView` helps:
https://github.com/jaydee3/JDDroppableView

You can also have a look on any of those threads:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=drag+drop+ios

Comment: I've used this code for 2images 



-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event{
UITouch *touch =[[event all touches]anyObject];
CGPoint location =[touch locationInView:touch.view];
if([touch view]==image1) {
image1.center=location ;
}
else if ([touch view]==image2) {
image2.center=location ;
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event{
[self touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

Comment: How can I make a view for each image it will make very big mess in my project